# run pg_dump in a docker container and output file to host

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump

We typically have to pg_dump from multiple different versions of databases. I want to run the command inside a Docker container with the right Postgres version and have the dump output to my files rather than the container.

I thought I'd achieve it like so;

```
docker run -it postgres:9.6.6-alpine pg_dump --file backupFile.bak --dbname=CONNECTIONSTRING --verbose --format=c --blobs > backupFile.bak
```

however this just outputs the terminal output of the pg_dump command to a file, not the actual dump. I end up with a local file that's just the verbose log of the command.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered mounting a volume or using `docker cp`?

Comment: @sp0gg I briefly looked into volumes but couldn't figure out if that's what I needed (bit of a docker noob here) - if that's the way to go I welcome an explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of two options here:

1. Mount a volume to a local folder and dump the file there. When the container exits, the file will still be there on the host. You wouldn't need to run the container interactively. The command might look something like this (not tested):

   ```
   docker run --rm -v <host_folder>:<container_folder> postgres:9.6.6-alpine pg_dump --file backupFile.bak --dbname=CONNECTIONSTRING --verbose --format=c --blobs
   ```

The backup file will still remain in `<host_folder>` after the container stops.

2. Start the container as-is, run `docker cp` to pull the file out of the container to the local filesystem, then stop the container. Probably not as easy or efficient as option 1.